# Monotouch custom UITableViewCell key value coding error

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, nib

Evaluating Monotouch for our project and getting this error:

> MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelJobNo.

This happens when I add label to a custom UITableViewCell xib and link it with ctrl-drag method.

If I just add label and don't link it, it works fine. Any idea how to fix it?

This is how JobListCell.designer.cs looks:

```
    [Register ("JobListCell")]
partial class JobListCell
{
    [Outlet]
    MonoTouch.UIKit.UILabel labelJobNo { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (labelJobNo != null) {
            labelJobNo.Dispose ();
            labelJobNo = null;
        }
    }
}
```